# Can text clips be converted into captions in Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere, closed-captioning

I have a Premiere Pro video project in which the subtitles have been created as titles with the Type Tool. Is there any way to convert the text clips on the timeline into captions, with the already set durations, or to export them as a subtitle file such as .srt?

Comment: Have you tried uploading to Youtube and using their automated caption creation tool?

Comment: Hi capogear, welcome to Video Production SE.  Unfortunately this doesn't really answer the question.  The user has already entered text clips with all the caption details and now needs to convert what they've already done.  The final post might also not be Youtube, so having Youtube do automated captions isn't really going to meet their needs.